# Reading bathymetry for coordinate with Python?

Tags: python, software-recommendations, bathymetry

I need the water depth at specific coordinates and my geoscientist are offering me a dataset in either TIFF or XYZ/txt format with data points each 2km.

I will typically be extracting about 1000000 points from the dataset in a single run of my application, and the dataset covers the entire Norwegian Continental Shelf.

I have never dealt with spatial data before, so **how do I extract the depth a certain x,y coordinates?**

The data would be used within an application written in Python, but of course a backend structure that parse the dataset could be in any other language as long as it provides an interface I can use in Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you could achieve what you want with the `rasterstat` Python library.
Here the documentation with a [basic example](https://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/manual.html#basic-example).