# Extract values from rasterstack TIFF for point data locations in Python

Tags: python, point, extract, machine-learning, rasterstack

I am working on machine learning algorithms for predicting wildfire sites on state level. I have a CSV of wildfire instances, that has 37 columns including a geometry column, a lat column and a lon column. I also have a stacked raster, in TIFF format of various climate and other associated variables. I am trying to use Python to extract the values from the stacked raster at the point locations (from the wildfire CSV) and create a data frame.

I have done a similar task before in R, using:

```
training <- raster::extract(raster_stack, wildfire, df=TRUE)
```

I have tried a couple of methods, similar to this response [Python - Extract raster values at point locations](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317391/python-extract-raster-values-at-point-locations)
and this one

```
with fiona.open('wildfire_gdb/wf_clip.shp') as shp:
    for feature in shp:
        wf_category = feature['properties']['FIRENAME']
        coords = feature['geometry']['coordinates']
        with rasterio.open('/Users/marie/Desktop/GI3/projekt/stacked.tif') as src:
            value = [v for v in src.sample([coords])][0][0]
        raster_values.loc['FIRENAME']=value
```

However, it just returns a CSV with a single cell of -3.4e+38, and think I am going wrong with calling the geometry or lat/lon values somewhere on a feature, 'FIRENAME' as I am not 100% sure what was meant by 'properties' and 'coordinates' in the code I tried to edit for my own use.

Sorry, I am new to this and not sure what other information you need that would be helpful and have searched everywhere and found nothing so far that gets me the output expected.

Comment: You should add some code ,&/or reference the Python libraries you have have used

Comment: I added some code and I have been trying to use the Fiona and Rasterio libraries.

Comment: I resolved this issue but using the correct inputs in the code found here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317391/python-extract-raster-values-at-point-locations