# Extract multiband raster values to point shapefile

Tags: geopandas, rasterio

I am trying to extract multiband (3 bands) raster values to a point shapefile.
In the following code, **centroids_gdf** is the variable that stores the point features.
**src** stores a list coming from tifs with a glob function.

Basically, I create centroids from a grid coincident to raster grid and then, assign the raster values to the point geodataframe. The code works but the problem is that it is repeating the point 3 times. I suspect that it is repeating the points per each band. How can I avoid this?

I saw this post, actually, I use the code from it, but it works for one single band.
[Python - Extract raster values at point locations](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317391/python-extract-raster-values-at-point-locations)

I have also seen other questions but I cannot find the proper answer.

```
import rasterio
import glob
import os
import geopandas as gpd


out_clip = "...\folder to store"

shapefile_areas = r"shapefile_areas.shp"

clips_folder = "...\clip"

the_tifs = glob.iglob(os.path.join(clips_folder,"*_clip.tif"))

tif_list = list(the_tifs) # I create this to iterate through the tifs later

#Read the shapefile into a GeoPandas dataframe. All areas
stdAreas = gpd.read_file(shapefile_areas)


names_StAreas = stdAreas["name"].unique()

the_grids_to_centroids_extraction = glob.iglob(os.path.join(out_clip,"grid_*.shp"))

name= 0

for glo in the_grids_to_centroids_extraction:

    display(glo)
    gdf_glo = gpd.read_file(glo)

    #extract the centroids! 
    centroids_ = gdf_glo.centroid


    #extract coordinates:

    centroids_.to_file(filename=os.path.join(out_clip+"\\centroid_values\\"+ names_StAreas[name]+"_centroids.shp"), driver='ESRI Shapefile')

    centroids_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gpd.GeoSeries(centroids_))
    
    #create geometry column
    centroids_gdf['geometry'] = None
    centroids_gdf['geometry'] = centroids_gdf[0]



    #Assign raster values
    centroids_gdf.index = range(len(centroids_gdf))
    coords = [(x,y) for x, y in zip(centroids_gdf['geometry'].x, centroids_gdf['geometry'].y)]

    # Open raster values (multiband)
    src = rasterio.open(tif_list[name])
    
    #Create each column for each band
    centroids_gdf['b'] = [x[0] for x in src.sample(coords)]
    centroids_gdf['g'] = [x[1] for x in src.sample(coords)]
    centroids_gdf['r'] = [x[2] for x in src.sample(coords)]

    del centroids_gdf[0]


    centroids_gdf.to_file(filename=os.path.join(out_clip+"test.shp"),diver = 'ESRI Shapefile')
```

Comment: You want one point shapefile with 3 columns for each raster?

Comment: Yes, for instance: field 'r', field 'g' and field 'b' . Actually, I got them but the same point is repeated 3 times.

Answer (score 2):

I found a possible solution. Maybe it is not efficient, as I calculated the "mean" of 1 value, but it is working with several rasters and polygons. I did not have to extract the values to points, it is enough to polygons.

These are the resources that I used, although I did not find the solution but they helped to research about this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50332455/concatenate-columns-of-dataframes-in-a-loop-pandas

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669482/appending-pandas-dataframes-generated-in-a-for-loop

Most useful:

[https://kodu.ut.ee/~kmoch/geopython2020/L5/raster.html#calculating-zonal-statistics](https://kodu.ut.ee/%7Ekmoch/geopython2020/L5/raster.html#calculating-zonal-statistics)

Basically, I am using the zonal_stats() function from rasterstats package.

```
from rasterstats import zonal_stats



#get the names of study areas
#all areas merged
shapefile_areas = "..\Study_areas.shp"


#Read the shapefile into a GeoPandas dataframe. All areas
stdAreas = gpd.read_file(shapefile_areas)


clips_folder = "..\clip"

the_tifs = glob.iglob(os.path.join(clips_folder,"*_clip.tif"))

out_clip = "...\extent"

the_grids_extraction = glob.iglob(os.path.join(out_clip,"grid_*.shp"))

list_grids = list(the_grids_extraction)

OUT_TEST = "...\folder"

names_StAreas = stdAreas["name"].unique()

count = 0

for i in the_tifs:

    dataset = rasterio.open(i)

    n_bands = dataset.count 
    
    print(n_bands)
    
    grids_gdf = gpd.read_file(list_grids[count])

    list_names_fields =['r','g','nir']

    for zstat in range(n_bands):
        
        # zonal statistics
        zs = zonal_stats(grids_gdf, i, stats=['mean'],band=zstat+1)

        display("-----")

        name_field = list_names_fields[zstat]

        stats_df = pd.DataFrame(zs)
        stats_df.rename(columns={'mean':list_names_fields[zstat]}, inplace=True)

        grids_gdf = pd.concat([grids_gdf, stats_df], axis=1)
        

        
        grids_gdf.to_file(os.path.join(OUT_TEST,names_StAreas[count]+'_rgbValues.shp'),driver='ESRI Shapefile')

        
        
    count = count +1
```

Comment: I feel like everything is in the rasterstats python module.