# Pixel value extraction with rasterio retrieves different value than QGIS

Tags: python, geopandas, rasterstats

I am extracting the pixel values from a raster using two different methods:
one is extracting the values to points (centroids of polygon grids)

```
folder = (...)
S2_green = "band_green.tif"
OS_green = os.path.join(folder, S2_green)

# Open the raster and store metadata
src = rasterio.open(OS_green)

centroids['lon'] = centroids['geometry'].x
centroids['lat'] = centroids['geometry'].y

coords = [(x,y) for x, y in zip(centroids.lon, centroids.lat)]

# Sample the raster at every point location and store values in DataFrame
centroids['Raster Value'] = [x for x in src.sample(coords)]
centroids['Raster Value'] = centroids.apply(lambda x: x['Raster Value'][0], axis=1)
```

(seen in [Python - Extract raster values at point locations](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317391/python-extract-raster-values-at-point-locations))

The other method is using the `zonal_stats()` function in `rasterstats` python library (as I have only one value, the "mean" should be the same value as the pixel)

Then, what I see is a small variation of value (see image took in QGIS pixel info).
Should I consider this as normal?

**Important**: all layers are in the same projection.

[image]

Comment: Agreed with BERA. I suspect 0.0678 was stored as an integer at some point and scaled by 0.0001. When it was converted to float there was precision errors which QGIS is probably rounding off.

Comment: What is the accuracy of the values ? [Demystifying Floating Point Precision](https://blog.demofox.org/2017/11/21/floating-point-precision/) and [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about this.  That makes sense, as the raster has a pixel depth of 2 bytes unsigned.