Find Python library to work with DEM in GeoTIFF format
I'm looking for a library for Python that will allow me to do the following thing:
I have a DEM in GeoTIFF format, and I have a list of points with coordinates in Lat/Lon format. I need these points to get elevation values based on the existing DEM.

What have you find and tried because unless you add a Python code attempt your question will be closed, There are many answers in GisSE

this is a simple point to pixel conversion

Rasterio:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317391/extracting-raster-values-at-point-locations-using-python

cross-post with  Searching a library for python
